# Вычисление количества ударов

Tags: c++

Нужно подсчитать количество потраченых ударов для убийства монстра. На вход поступают: начальный урон [`d`], увеличение урона при каждом ударе (арифметическая прогрессия, `an=a1+d*n`) [`k`], и количество жизней у монстра [`hp`]. Нужно найти максимально быстро количество ударов.

Ограничение по времени: 1с.

Ограничение по памяти: 256Мб.

Входные данные:
1≤K≤10^3,
1≤D≤10^5,
1≤hp≤10^15

У меня есть набросок кода, но он по времени не успевает обрабатывать.. Данные подаются с Файла (input.txt), выход в другой файл (output.txt);

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    ifstream fin ("input.txt");
    unsigned long long  res = 0,dn,res_n;
    long double hp;
    int k, d;
    fin >> k >> d >> hp;
    res_n = 0;
    while (hp>0){
        hp = hp - d;
        d = d + k;
        res_n++;
    }
    res =res_n;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("output.txt");
    fout << res;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А формулу суммы арифметической прогрессии применить не судьба?...

Comment: а как из нее выразить n??

Comment: решить уравнение (точнее - неравенство)

Comment: Элементарно, Ватсон :) Если бы я вообще понимал, что у вас считывается (читает n, прибавляете k, говорите в тексте об a1, пишете "количество" с двумя л :)), я бы даже написал формулу. Но у вас настолько неаккуратно все написано... Привели бы исходное условие или URL.

Comment: Можете пояснить? Я не до конца понял, что вы хотите сказать..

Comment: он имеет в виду что вам стоит назвать свои переменные более осмысленно.

Comment: а вообще по факту надо решить квадратное уравнение.

Comment: Ну что, формулу для суммы арифм. прогрессии удалось найти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сумма арифм. прогрессии: [image: сумма арифм. прогрессии]

d*n^2 +(2*a - d)*n - 2*Sn = 0

дискриминант: **D = (2*a - d)^2 + 8*d*Sn**

**n = (sqrt(D) - 2*a + d) / 2*d**

"n" округлить в верхнюю сторону

*P.S. тут указаны общие формулировки, вот названия из твоего проекта*
*мои переменные -- переменные из кода*
**a == d

d == k

Sn == hp**